# How to make anchor tag fit to content? not entire width of page

Tags: html, css

I have got the look I desire with my css. A centered `<p>` and `<div>` one on top of the other and they are both wrapped in `<a>` tags.

Now my issue is that the `<a>` tags go for the entire width of the page, I just want to be able to click on the link where the actual content is.

example link:
https://jsfiddle.net/vinko_k_design/dge4fx2z/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the anchor tags inside the `p` tag.

```
 <p class="page-nav"><a href="#map">Check out our Map</a></p>
```

Comment: This worked for the `<p>` tag but not the red box inside the `<div>` . Any idea on how to make that work?

Comment: Put the `page-nav-img` class on the `<a>` tag itself: `<a href="#map" class="page-nav-img"></a>`

Answer (score 4):

Using a `span` (inline element) instead of a `div`/`p` (block element), and moving the `text-align` property to the upper level will fix your issue. As follows:

```css
.page-nav-buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

.page-nav {
}

.page-nav-img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-nav-buttons">
    <a href="#map">
        <span class="page-nav">Check out our Map</span>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a href="#map">
        <span class="page-nav-img"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for the `<p>` tag but not the red box inside the `<div>` . Any idea on how to make that work?

Comment: Updated my answer. There's a million ways to do this. The important thing to take away from this is the difference between inline and block-level elements. Once you come to terms with that, the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/dge4fx2z/1/

```
 <div class="page-nav-buttons">
  <p class="page-nav"> <a href="#map">
    Check out our Map
 </a>

 </p> <span class="page-nav-img">
 <a href="#map">

     <span class="page-nav-img"></span>

 </a>
 </span>
</div>
```